# How to continue with the main program when threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run a thread in python and am fairly new at it. While going through the basics, when I start a thread, the program doesn't continue with the main program and is stuck in the thread. i.e. it prints only "hello world" and never prints "hi there".

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def hello_world():
    while True:
        print("hello world")
        time.sleep(5)

t = Thread(target = hello_world())
t.start()

print("hi there")
```

I'm using spyder IDE.

I searched online for some basic programs in threading but for those, the code works.

How should I proceed?

Comment: `target = hello_world()` you are calling `hello_world` before actually creating thread. remove `()`.

Comment: You should pass your function as a reference, i.e. without `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line `t = Thread(target = hello_world())`.

You are trying to create a `Thread` with the `target` argument. According to the order of evaluation, Python first needs to know what to assign to `target`, so it evaluates the RHS. In your case the RHS is `hello_world()`. So the function is already being called in that exact moment!

So the function executes and enters the infinite loop and the `Thread` is never even created and your program is stuck.

What you would want to do is pass to `target` a mere **reference** to the function, so change said line to:

```py
t = Thread(target = hello_world)
```

And now the RHS is evaluated as a reference to the given function, and behind the scenes the `Thread` will be created, making the call to that function, and your main Thread will keep running as expected.